# Camera x imageCapture.takePicture function is not working on android 12

Tags: java, androidx, android-camerax

Here i'm trying to take pictures using camerax , it is working with below android 12 devices perfectly but when use android 12 device it is not working.

```
 long x = System.currentTimeMillis();


            String fileName = getExternalFilesDir(null) + "" + x + ".jpg";


            File file = new File(fileName);

            ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions = new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(file).build();
            imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions, executor, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {


                @Override
                public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                    Log.e("xxxx", "yyy");
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```

i debugged the code and put a brake-point in onError function , but it is not called

Comment: Does the same code works on lower API level?

Comment: yes , android 11

Comment: Do you mind filing a bug? Sounds like something needs to be fixed. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=618491&template=1257717